# Airflow send slack message to multiple channels

Tags: airflow

I work with apache airflow and I want to send messages to multiple channels and I wonder what is the best solution.
I have my script:

```
t_success_notification = SlackAPIPostOperator(
task_id = 'success-notification'
, trigger_rule = 'all_success'
, channel = '#channel1'
, token = ...
, text = "success"
, dag = dag)

t_success_notification.set_upstream(task1)
```

So what should I do to send notification also to #channel2. Can I just list the channels after coma like:

```
...
, channel = '#channel1,#channel2,#channel3'
...
```

Does anyone know how to do it ? Kind regards

Comment: Looking into the code, only one channel is allowed: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/slack_operator.py I suppose one way would be other tasks and another way to code your own Slack Operator derived from the on linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to set this up would be to use this Slack integration to get an email address for a channel:
https://astronomerteam.slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email

This gives us an email address that's associated with a channel. We then just drop this email address in the `email` arg for a DAG. This makes it so we don't have to use a separate operator for any Slack channel notifications, and can easily send alerts to multiple channels (for success, retry, failure, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do it with the otherwise-easy-to-use SlackPostOperator.  If you look at the code for the SlackPostOperator: https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/slack_operator.html it uses the code for the SlackAPI: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient and you can see from the documentation that it doesn't take multiple channels as parameters.

As another poster mentioned - a good solution is to create email aliases for each slack channel and then you can add those emails to the email settings in the Default Args section. I.e.:
    "email": ["channel1_integration@slack.com", 
              "channel2_integration@slack.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,